Why is ~使ってしまって used here?
A Japanese person told me:

ややこしい日本語を使ってしまって ごめんなさい

While I understood the meaning of the sentence, I did not understand the grammar.

Why did she use 使ってしまって, and not just 使って?


ややこしい日本語を使って ごめんなさい


Why end the sentence with the -te form しまって? Is this manner of speech something called お嬢様言葉?


Although しまう is usually introduced with the 'do something completely' meaning, I find that the 'unfortunately' meaning is more common. She was not trying to be confusing, but things ended up that way, so しまう.
The sentence does not end with the て form - I find it unusual that you're aware of the お嬢様言葉 use, but not that apologies and thanks follow the て form or the 連用形. 「遅れてすみませんでした」　「最後まで読んでくれてありがとう」

Although しまう is usually introduced with the 'do something completely' meaning, I find that the 'unfortunately' meaning is more common.  I typically find the opposite to be true, and in my beginner studies we were taught the "unfortunately" meaning first.
